# Java error : java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to MyCustomClass

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have the following code;

```
private List<MyCustomClassVO> copyMyCustomClassList(List<MyCustomClass> fromList) {
    for (MyCustomClass myCustomClassObj : fromList) {

    }
}
```

Now I am getting an error

> error : java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to MyCustomClass

This is for the statement `for (MyCustomClass myCustomClassObj : fromList)`

I just debugged and checked `fromList`. It has all the variables set as defined in `MyCustomClass`. But in the debug, it shows `fromList` type as `Vector`, with each member of the list showing as type `Object[]`.

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: For some reason, I don't see an error there. Can you show, how exactly you're calling this method and what's the parameter which is being passed to it?

Comment: I am calling this method as 
copyMyCustomClassList(responseList.get(0).getRecords())

Comment: Now responseList is actually populated after executing a named query. It has 2 members; Long totalRecords; and List<T> records;

Comment: Add more code what exactly you trying to do . I see incompleteness.

Answer (score 1):

Your method may be called something like this.

```
List objectsList = new ArrayList();
objectsList.add(new Object());
objectsList.add(new Object());
objectsList.add(new Object());


List<MyCustomClassVO> voList = copyMyCustomClassList(objectsList);
```

You need to make sure that the list being passed to the method contains elements that are of type `MyCustomClassVO` or its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`fromList` definitely seems to be `List<Object>` in runtime. Since **generics** are **erased**, `List<Object>` gets assigned to `fromList` which is `List<MyCustomClass>` without any issue. But the code fails at *for-each* loop where `Object` gets cast to `MyCustomClass`

Best you can do is check how `fromList` is populated

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert objectDataList which is of type Object into List of MyCustomClass as following method.

```
ArrayList<MyCustomClass> mylist = (ArrayList<MyCustomClass>) (Object) objectDataList;
for (MyCustomClass myCustomClassObj : mylist) {
    System.out.println("myCustomClassObj : " + myCustomClassObj);
}
```